# Send Push notification when product was approved on appstore only

Tags: php, iphone, apple-push-notifications

We have an application, which sells "downloadable" products. 
Scenario is:

1. Add product to our backend (powered on php and symfony)
2. Add product to apple store and wait when it will be approved
3. Sell it.

It works like a charm.

But I'd like to implement push notification, when new product is added to our store. The problem is that I don't know if the produc was approved and is available on Apple side.
It may confuse a user, when he sees the notification about 1 new product, but it is unavailable and the user doesn't even see it on application.

Is there a way to get approved and available product list from Apple?

Comment: I am not sure can you try if SKProductsResponse give an invalid product identifier if its not approved

Comment: I have to check products on my PHP-backend. Not on application. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey, try parsing emails, that you get from App Store when new product is approved. This will make all notification up to date and you won't miss any user

Comment: Good idea! Btw, that's a reason why I hate apple! Everything for users, nothing for developers.

Answer (score 0):

Jus implement on your server an module that fetches the apple product to see if it is there.

http://developer.apple.com/news/ios/archives/2010/january/

> Drive Customers Directly to Your App on
>   the App Store with iTunes Links With
>   iTunes links you can provide your
>   customers with an easy way to access
>   your apps on the App Store directly
>   from your website or marketing
>   campaigns. Creating an iTunes link is
>   simple and can be made to direct
>   customers to either a single app, all
>   your apps, or to a specific app with
>   your company name specified.
>
> To send customers to a specific
>   application:
>   http://itunes.com/apps/appname
>
> To send
>   customers to a list of apps you have
>   on the App Store:
>   http://itunes.com/apps/developername
>
> To send customers to a specific app
>   with your company name included in the
>   URL:
>   http://itunes.com/apps/developername/appname
>
> For more details on creating iTunes
>   links, read: Creating easy-to-read
>   links to the App Store for your
>   applications and company.

Or [Creating easy-to-read links to the App Store for your applications and company](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1633/_index.html)

Comment: I didn't get your answer. You said about direct link to application, but I'd like to see example of code for getting products from store. Links which you provided don't have answer to my question. They only answer on "How to print direct link to application".

Comment: By the way, you said "Jus implement on your server an module that fetches the apple product to see if it is there.". And yes, I need it, but I can't find it.